# Working with Semantic UI's Stub Files

Tags: css, less, semantic-ui

I am currently starting development based on Semantic UI.
In Semantic UI's Customization Guide, the use of the empty *Stub Files*, contained in the delivery.

As kind of a "proof of concept" for me, I try to modify some variables of the Button-Element.

If I understand the principle of customizing correctly, I shall customize all these variable within these stub files.
So I edit */site/elements/button.variables* to

```
@defaultBorderRadius: 3rem;
```

which leads to more rounded button corners.

Also I am able to define this definition within */themes/default/globals/site.variables*, yielding the same effect. But this is no stub file.

If I now try to implement this definition in */site/globals/site.variables*, this effect doesn't take place.

Assuming this is no bug in Semantic UI, I think I must have misunderstood the theming concept.

Can someone clarify that for me?

Thanks in advance,
Sascha.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken if you define it in `button.variables` it applies only to `@defaultBorderRadius` code inside inside a button ruleset(s). Same variable in `site.variables` will apply to *any* ruleset... Indeed those stub files maybe quite confusing in use, but it's expected since they try to keep less or more same code organization for both Less (lazy-evaluation + wise-scope) and SCSS (greedy-evaluation + poor-scope-notion) versions (as result collecting all weirdness and disadvantages from both :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @seven-phases-max!
Indeed defining the variable in site.variables  `site.variables` doesn't yield any effect. That's my problem.
And I mean global `site.variables`, under folder _site/_, not the one within _themes/_ (please see explanation of difference above).

Comment: Try to use `*.overrides` instead of `*.variables` (as far as I understand `*.overrides` files are supposed to be used to actually *override* default stuff...). As for `site/` vs. `themes/`, indeed, the import chain there is too complex to say for sure why this or that happens...

Comment: I found out the root of problem:

Since I am working according Semantic UI's build guidelines (http://learnsemantic.com/guide/expert.html#gulp-commands), I am running the Watch task in the background.

If changing _/site/globals/site.variables_, `gulp watch` apparently doesn't recompile `button.css`. To get this file compiled anew, I need to do some change in `button.less`, in order to notify Semantic UI to rebuild the Button element.

Comment: Ah, nice. It would be worth if you add this as the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I did it.

Comment: And it's absolutely fine to accept your own answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the root of problem:

Since I am working according Semantic UI's build guidelines (learnsemantic.com/guide/expert.html#gulp-commands), I am running the Watch task in the background.

If changing */site/globals/site.variables*, `gulp watch` apparently doesn't recompile button.css. To get this file compiled anew, I need to do some change in *button.less*, in order to notify Semantic UI to rebuild the Button element.